# Where does rude start?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, etiquette

I just found out that I can check how my flags turned out to be. And I'm somewhat surprised by one of them:

- Poster asks a (duplicate) question about how to get a string value
- Someone comments "Did you try `str(...)`?`"
- OP replies with "Yeah that does it, FFFUUUU.... :P"

I flagged the last comment for being rude which was rejected. I understand that some may see this as non-rude behavior, but to me, the combination of

- Not thanking for a response, but rather
- Writing "fuck you :P"

is kind of disturbing. I understand that OP rather expressed his frustration about the triviality of the solution (and maybe his own stupidity), but

**Being rude is not about how you intend a comment, but about how it's being understood on the other side**.

I'm not providing a link since I try to avoid meta effects, but I only have two flags so those really interested can find the post themselves. My question, somewhat implied:

Was the comment still okay? Am I expecting too much from the community?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ffffuuuu

Comment: FooBar, you got this all wrong, what he means by FU is Functional Update,

"Yeah that does it, FFFunctional UUUUpdates.... :P"

Comment: It's an abbrevation.  The full meme is FFFFFUUUUUUBBBBAAAAARRRRR!!!

Comment: Not sure it was so much F.U. but more FUuuu... I screwed up...

Comment: Possible answers also here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338470/rude-flag-declined-on-question-link?noredirect=1#comment415158_338470

Comment: "Being rude is not about how you intend a comment, but about how it's being understood on the other side."

Nope. Rudeness is about intention as well as action.

What you're talking about is "Taking offence". Anyone is entitled to take offence at what they want to. It doesn't mean anyone has been rude to them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an interjection, a generic expression of [rage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_comic) (or in this case, mild frustration or self-deprecation). It isn't attacking anybody. You're reading too much into it.

But if it *really* bothers you, you can always flag it as too chatty instead. Personally I don't see it as rude.

Comment: that's right, it doesn't "stand for" F. U. It's slowly slowly starting to say just the first word of that phrase, because you're angry with yourself for making a simple mistake or with the tool you're using for being sensitive to such a small thing, but stopping before you say the whole word. You can mentally replace it with "oh, bother" if you like. Nothing rude about it.

Answer (score 7):

I went to Franklin. So when they ask me in job interviews, "where did you go to college?", I stand up and tell them FU!