# A post with an image containing bad words in it isn't rude or abusive?

Tags: support, rude-or-abusive

I've flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915400/cd-cannot-find-path-because-it-does-not-exist) as Rude or Abusive due to the bad words in the image of the code it has. It was declined.

Shouldn't I flag when I see those things? Or it is acceptable to have bad words in images on this site?

Comment: Programmers use weird stuff for testing. R/A is more for posts which are unrecoverable and should simply be deleted.

Comment: So, it is acceptable, @Nick?

Comment: That image alone does not constitute a valid minimal reproducible example, so one better thing to do here is to vote to close the question (or in your case flag it as such). In the process, one could suggest the user to replace profanity in the code, through a comment.

Comment: For the record, it took me quite a while to find the offensive part. For an R/A flag without/little context it is probably just not obvious enough that something is wrong with the question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, if I could write something to explain why I flagged, I would. But we don't have a field there to do that.

Comment: I declined it, because of what @MisterMiyagi said. I legitimately didn't see it. Now that I do see it, I'll have to second Nick (read: would've declined anyway). It's one word (that isn't considered hate speech, may I add) in one image that's presumably used for testing. I don't see any way to justify an R/A hammer on it over that. An edit, sure, but that's tricky when it's an image (i.e. you can just remove it. It's not an MCVE anyway, as E_net4 mentions, so it really doesn't matter), but an R/A flag is overkill for "fuck". And you do have a field for explaining why; it's called a mod flag

Comment: Expanding on what Zoe said, R/A deletions carry a heavy penalty (-100 rep), for minor offences that's not really necessary.

Comment: ... and expanding on what Nick said, it also contributes towards an IP ban, making further contributions harder or impossible, depending on the user and IP. The question was made in good faith as well; that kind of response isn't warranted in this particular case.

Comment: Use R/A flags for unsalvageable garbage that should be deleted *immediately*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I'll use this flag only for things serious, like hate speech, for instance...

Comment: I conclude @Nick expands on the diamond from Zoe ...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado: Probably a good rule of thumb is whether it’s directed at a contributor or a broader group. There is plenty of rude content that gets removed because it’s directed at other contributors, but which isn’t profane nor hate speech (“Did you even bother trying? Why are you wasting our time?”). And hate speech itself is, by definition, directed at a group (and especially a protected demographic), even when it’s also targeting an individual. If someone is just being salty with their language because they’re frustrated with their code, editing is better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rule of thumb on how to handle any post (question or answer) with profanity is in asking yourself: **does it stand by itself as a question/answer even if the profanity was removed?** Rude/Abusive flags are reserved for unsalvageable content which should be deleted as soon as possible, and thus bear fitting consequences to the author. If the post *is* salvageable, the recommended course of action is to edit out the profanity.

In this case however, the profanity was behind an image, which contained nearly all of the context of the question. Removing the image would mean removing all context as well. That alone is another problem, the question does not provide a proper minimal reproducible example. Flagging/voting to close it would be a good idea, optionally followed by suggesting to remove any profanity in any eventual reiteration of the question.

Frankly, editing the question to only remove the image could still be done, but the image was sitting behind a link (as a consequence of the user not having enough reputation to embed it), meaning that the profanity was not immediately shown, and overall it does not amount to something extremely offensive nor something that could befall on the line of bigotry or NSFW. An accepted rude/abusive flag would have had too grave a consequence for this user, who just threw in a few "f*** you" lines in the code out of desperation over their non-functioning code.

That it was behind a link also made it harder for moderators to quickly identify where the rudeness is. In the event that the inappropriate portions of the post are not easily seen in plain sight, prefer a flag for moderator attention describing the situation in detail.

See also:

- [Rude flag declined on question + link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338470)

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, profanity is neither necessary nor sufficient to constitute rudeness or abuse. To claim otherwise seems rather childish and silly, [prevalent as it may be](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=7291). I see condescending comments on this site relatively often, but they rarely happen to use the word ‘fuck’ — passive aggression usually suffices, plus it helps escape the moderation’s radar.

On the other hand, if the profanity is truly gratuitous and can be edited out without changing the substance of the question, it should. It's not like swearing is a primary goal of this site either. At the very least, that screenshot could have been cropped, or the relevant console output could have been transcribed into the question body, without impacting answerability.

But on the third hand, profanity or not, this particular question doesn't seem to be a particularly good one anyway: It looks like the problem described was caused by a typo and the question would not have been of any help to anyone else but the original asker.