Declined flag - rude language should have been edited out
I recently flagged a post as "rude /abusive" that multiple persons within the comments found to be insulting. The OP used inappropriate swearing words and sentences referring to parents (without going into full detail).
The flag was declined as:

The issue(s) you note with this post can be corrected simply by editing it. Even anonymous users have the ability to suggest edits to posts. This does not require moderator intervention.

I don't understand how reporting inappropriate language or swearing is wrong and why curators should just remove those by editing. What are those flags then for?

This seems on point - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412980/a-post-with-an-image-containing-bad-words-in-it-isnt-rude-or-abusive

""Rude/Abusive flags are reserved for unsalvageable content which should be deleted as soon as possible, and thus bear fitting consequences to the author. If the post is salvageable, the recommended course of action is to edit out the profanity""

I see the link is helpful. Maybe it would overall be helpful to add this to the flag description.

To be fair the community actually does want moderators to atleast mark these flags as helpful. See this question and the scores of the various answers: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416047/an-asker-inserted-insults-in-a-question-edit-a-rude-or-abusive-flag-was-raise (If you read this answer though, you'd understand this is actually a problem with the flag tooling)

If the user in question insists in bringing that verbiage into the question, then that would be a good time to flag the post for moderator attention. Often what I do on isolated first incidents of posts being edited to include rude meta-commentary is remove such meta-commentary and follow the post.

Moderators are exception handlers that should be called in on situations that can't be resolved with normal use. If the profanity can simply be edited out without too much effort, then that's the best course of action. If the user then reverts that edit, you have reason to flag...

@Cerbrus to my normal logic a breach of the CoC is an exceptional issue that should be handled by moderator such at any other place. The link that was commented above gives more insight for the technical reason. The normal users will not be default understand why insulting or profanity should be curator handled. A normal user will look at a flag description when flagging not consult Meta first.

And then that normal user would be informed they can just edit out the profanity. Issue resolved!

But if the words and the moderators’ actions actually matched, there wouldn’t have been an issue to resolve in the first place, and people wouldn’t be wasting their time…

As much as some folks are interested in seeing greater sanctions applied (or at least keeping record for future measures) over users committing occasional CoC violations in posts, the current policy is to only flag posts as Rude/Abusive when said posts are unsalvageable. That I know of, it there has not been a substantial feature request to change this.

Not the handling mod, but this case was also an exceedingly minor use of profanity: two lines similar to <h2 id="heading">f**k</h2> (except it wasn't asterisks) in an otherwise innocuous HTML sample.  This was not really being rude to others; it was a one-off choice of inappropriate sample text.  While it should of course be removed via editing, it's at most barely a CoC violation (in contrast with the example shared by @AbdulAzizBarkat, which is quite clearly a CoC violation and attacks both a specific user and the community as a whole).
